# How is magic damage calculated in Infinity Blade 2?

Tags: infinity-blade-2

Let x be the power of the ring (ice 4) for example, and y be your magic. What's the damage, and how long does it take for magic to recharge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formula - YOUR MAGIC DAMAGE = BASE(N) * (0.657 * LOG(MAGIC STATS) - 1.096);

- Base(n) depends on the tier of your ring, ranging from 1 (High Storm, Worm Hole etc.) to 8 (Diruel).
- Base(1): 100
- Base(2): 300
- Base(3): 500
- Base(4): 1000
- Base(5): 2000
- Base(6): unknown
- Base(7): (Devotion & Cog): 3500
- Base(8): (Diruel):4000
- "log(magic stats)" refers to the natural logarithm of your magic stats.

Found on [this](http://forums.epicgames.com/threads/912268-Predicting-your-magic-damage-formula) website.

Comment: So magic has "diminishing marginal return"?

Comment: It seems like it. Therefore, this calculation can tell you whether or not you want to improve your magic anymore.

Comment: What about The Holy Ring?